# Is there a way to create a string out of a key-value pair from a dictionary in python?

Tags: python

E.g. I have a dictionary:

```
{"John": "Doe", "Jane" : "Smith", "Jack" : "Poland"}
```

I want to create a list

```
["John Doe", "Jane Smith", "Jack Poland"]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code!

Comment: Add you code to the question. In a comment it is unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The f-string in a list comprehension would be the most efficient, which it looks like someone already answered.

Another way, which might be easier to wrap your head around, would be to just do a `for` loop and iterate through the dictionary once. Use some python string concatenation, which you may have learned already and then append it to a new list.
(FYI: The f-string approach has same result with less code)

Using string concatenation:

```
full_name = []
name_dict = {"John": "Doe", "Jane" : "Smith", "Jack" : "Poland"} 

for first, last in name_dict.items():
    name = first + " " + last
    full_name.append(name)
    
print(full_name)
```

There are a few other ways too, but this one and the f-string popped out at me right off the bat.

You could also define multiple variables and lists at the top, which would be a little less confusing than putting everything on one line and similar to other exercises you may have done and is also more organized.

Another neat thing is that you have the name within a separate variable in the for loop; that is not yet in your new list until you append it. This is cool because you can use the variable too if you want to do anything else with combined string other than just append it to the list.

Answer (score 1):

Given dict `names`, you can use an f-string in a list comprehension.

```
[f'{key} {value}' for key, value in names.items()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
    dic = {"John": "Doe", "Jane" : "Smith", "Jack" : "Poland"}
    lst =[key+" "+value for key,value in dic.items()]
    print(lst)
```

output:

```
['Jack Poland', 'John Doe', 'Jane Smith']
```